# Return result based on multiple values AND set value based on result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

1. I'm trying to return rows based on the values in multiple columns. I need to return member data. Each member has a 'DiagnosisID' and 'CategoryScore'. The min(DiagnosisID) is 'MostSevereDiagnosis'. I need to return the mostseverediagnosis for each CategoryScore for each patient. So for example, one member has two different CategoryScores, so I need to return both, but another member has the same CategoryScore twice, and I need to return only the one with min(diagnosisid). My code is below, but I can't group by CategoryScore or I get an error.
2. I need to create column 'IsMostSevereCategory' (my current case when clause is incorrect for this, but I don't know how else to do it). It needs to be set to 1 for the min(categoryscore) for each member and for any null values; but must be set to 0 for the rest.

Current query:

```
SELECT 
 sq.MemberID, 
 sq.FirstName, 
 sq.LastName, 
 sq.DiagnosisID AS MostSevereDiagnosis, 
 diagnosisdescription, 
 DiagnosisCategoryID, 
 CategoryDescription, 
 CategoryScore,
 CASE WHEN DiagnosisCategoryID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsMostSevereCategory

FROM
 (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mem.memberid ORDER BY md.DiagnosisID ASC) AS ROWNUM,
 mem.MemberID, 
 mem.FirstName, 
 mem.LastName, 
 md.DiagnosisID, 
 d.diagnosisdescription,
 dc.DiagnosisCategoryID, 
 dc.CategoryDescription, 
 dc.CategoryScore
 from dbo.member mem 
 left join dbo.Memberdiagnosis md on mem.MemberID = md.MemberID
 left join Diagnosis d on md.DiagnosisID = d.DiagnosisID
 left join DiagnosisCategoryMap dcm on d.DiagnosisID = dcm.DiagnosisID
 left join DiagnosisCategory dc on dc.DiagnosisCategoryID = dcm.DiagnosisCategoryID) sq
WHERE ROWNUM =1
```

Current Results are:

```
MemID FIRST     LAST   MostSevere DiagDesc  CatID  CatDesc CatScore IsMostSevere
1   John      Smith     2        Diag2      2      CatB    20       0
1   John      Smith     4        Diag4      3      CatC    30       0
2   Jack      Smith    NULL      NULL      NULL    NULL    NULL     1
3   Will      Smyth     3        Diag3      3      CatC    30       0
3   Will      Smyth     4        Diag4      3      CatC    30       0
```

So basically I need Row 1 and Row 4 to have IsMostSevere = 1; and need to remove row 5.

Comment: Why are you using ROWNUM on your subquery ?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified. I just edited my post. I originally had WHERE ROWNUM = 1 so that only the MostSevereDiagnosis would return. But then it doesn't return both CategoryScore values for MemberID 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, tell me if it doesn't work.
I reworked on your Row_number put your query on a CTE format to make it more readable and created another query to get the mincat score.

```
    WITH C AS(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mem.memberid,DiagnosisCategoryID ORDER BY md.DiagnosisID ASC) AS ROWNUM,
               mem.MemberID, 
               mem.FirstName, 
               mem.LastName, 
               md.DiagnosisID, 
               d.diagnosisdescription,
               dc.DiagnosisCategoryID, 
               dc.CategoryDescription, 
               dc.CategoryScore
         FROM dbo.member mem 
         LEFT JOIN dbo.Memberdiagnosis md on mem.MemberID = md.MemberID
         LEFT JOIN Diagnosis d on md.DiagnosisID = d.DiagnosisID
         LEFT JOIN DiagnosisCategoryMap dcm on d.DiagnosisID = dcm.DiagnosisID
         LEFT JOIN DiagnosisCategory dc on dc.DiagnosisCategoryID = dcm.DiagnosisCategoryID
        ),D AS(
        SELECT min(categoryscore) AS mincat
              ,MemberID
        FROM dbo.member mem 
          LEFT JOIN dbo.Memberdiagnosis md on mem.MemberID = md.MemberID
          LEFT JOIN Diagnosis d on md.DiagnosisID = d.DiagnosisID
          LEFT JOIN DiagnosisCategoryMap dcm on d.DiagnosisID = dcm.DiagnosisID
          LEFT JOIN DiagnosisCategory dc on dc.DiagnosisCategoryID = dcm.DiagnosisCategoryID
GROUP BY MemberID
        )
        SELECT  C.MemberID, 
                C.FirstName, 
                C.LastName, 
                C.DiagnosisID AS MostSevereDiagnosis, 
                C.diagnosisdescription, 
                C.DiagnosisCategoryID, 
                C.CategoryDescription, 
                C.CategoryScore,
                CASE WHEN D.mincat = C.CategoryScore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsMostSevereCategory
        FROM C
        LEFT JOIN D ON (C.MemberID = D.MemberID)
        WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: Got a few errors. First one was an issue with one of the joins. Changed it to:  
    FROM dbo.Memberdiagnosis md LEFT JOIN Member mem on md.MemberID = mem.MemberID

Now I'm getting "Invalid column name 'CatID'

Comment: I changed it, try it again

Comment: Getting this error:  
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Column 'dbo.member.MemberID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I forgot the GROUP BY MemberID

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
The multi-part identifier "sq.MemberID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
The multi-part identifier "sq.FirstName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
The multi-part identifier "sq.LastName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
The multi-part identifier "sq.DiagnosisID" could not be bound.

Comment: try again. i changed outer query again

Comment: It's running successfully now, and looks good, except I need the "IsMostSevereCategory" to be = 1 for NULL values. It is currently set to 0

Comment: Never mind, I just added OR c.categoryscore is null to the case when and it's working now. Thanks!